# Query/Function to trace dependents/predecesors in Teradata?

Tags: sql, database, teradata, data-mapping

I need to trace the object dependencies in Teradata. 
MS SQL Server has this served on a platter within 2 clicks (view dependencies).
In Teradata, for the 1st level dependencies I've checked the DBC.Tables for data definitions with:

```
select * from DBC.Tables 
where RequestText like '%My_DB.My_Table%' 
and DatabaseName||TableName not like '%My_DB%My_Table%'
```

Is there a way to check any 2nd level+ dependencies without using cursors?
With cursors I can catch the results of the 1st level and run the query again on the result to check any 2nd level. Then iterate that till activitycount = 0 on the select. (haven't yet tried this, but i'm sure it works).So i'm looking for something a bit simpler than a SP.

Comment: Can you provide more information about what do you have exactly in DBC.Tables?

Comment: the DBC schema/database is the master metadata repository of Teradata (the main user or DB if you like). In DBC.Tables you can find names and data definition for all Tables, Views, Procedures or Macros. (see this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_metadata) for comparison with Oracle metadata

Comment: The Oracle's standard metadata table is called ALL_TABLES as far as I know and also the link you sent confirms that. But in your query it is named just Tables. Isn't that something else? A Teradata specific table maybe? Also the column names are different in the ALL_TABLES table

Answer (score 1):

This topic was covered in an article on the Teradata Developer Exchange, [Extract and Analyse Database Object Dependencies](https://developer.teradata.com/blog/ulrich/2011/11/extract-and-analyse-database-object-dependencies), which may help point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks, It looks like what i needed and it's worth a try for everyone else. Still while checking the solution proposed on the page I had to kill the query several times after more that 15 min to fill the volatile table (step1) ... with filters on a single, small-scale DB.

Comment: Do you have the stats on the DBC tables as recommended? Or even additional stats to help support the SQL to build the volatile table?